# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError on Activity.showDialog (int, Bundle)?

Tags: java, android, showdialog, nosuchmethoderror

Here is what LogCat says:

```
01-21 17:20:06.057: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27463): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.mohit.geo2do.activities.TasksList.showDialog
01-21 17:20:06.057: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27463):     at com.mohit.geo2do.activities.TasksList.onContextItemSelected(TasksList.java:190)
01-21 17:20:06.057: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27463):     at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2183)
01-21 17:20:06.057: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27463):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$ContextMenuCallback.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:2785)
01-21 17:20:06.057: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27463):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:140)
01-21 17:20:06.057: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27463):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:855)
01-21 17:20:06.057: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27463):     at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuDialogHelper.onClick(MenuDialogHelper.java:129)
01-21 17:20:06.057: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27463):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:898)
01-21 17:20:06.057: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27463):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:301)
01-21 17:20:06.057: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27463):     at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3626)
01-21 17:20:06.057: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27463):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3600)
01-21 17:20:06.057: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27463):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
01-21 17:20:06.057: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27463):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-21 17:20:06.057: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27463):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-21 17:20:06.057: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27463):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
01-21 17:20:06.057: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27463):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-21 17:20:06.057: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27463):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-21 17:20:06.057: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27463):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:862)
01-21 17:20:06.057: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27463):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
01-21 17:20:06.057: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(27463):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I get an error at this phrase:

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putLong("id", ...);           //Some arbitrary value
showDialog(DELETE_DIALOG, args);
```

I have an `onPrepareDialog` method:

```
@Override
protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog, Bundle args) {
    switch (id) {
    case DELETE_DIALOG:
        AlertDialog log = (AlertDialog) dialog;
        final Bundle bundle = args;
        log.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                long id = bundle.getLong("id");

                getContentResolver().delete(Tasks.CONTENT_URI, Tasks._ID + "=" + id, null);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: What is the code for your `showDialog()` method?

Comment: The code is in the Android platform code.

Comment: Weird. Didn't know you called dialogs that way. @.@ Was confused, nevermind. :P

Comment: Which one is the line where the error occurs?

Comment: @Beasly It occurs at this line in the first code block (besides the LogCat): showDialog(DELETE_DIALOG, args);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally that means the class you compiled against and the class you're running against are different versions. The method you are calling was accessible to your compiler but is not available to the JVM at runtime.

Comment: nice answer +1  brother Speck !!

Answer (score 2):

Only API8 and upper has it. lower than it only has Activity.showDialog (int).