# Android bluetooth socket connected state

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

In my android application I need to perform an operation just to check if the `bluetooth socket` is connected before goes to the next state.

In manifest file I have defined `android:minSdkVersion="7" And android:targetSdkVersion="17"`.

So I can use the **isConnected()** method available in bluetooth Socket class to check this. But this method have added in `API level 14` and since my `android:targetSdkVersion="17"` it compiles well and properly installs in my device.

But the problem is in run time it provides me with the following error.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.isConnected
```

Also this error does not occur with the devices that runs Android OS version 4.0 (API level 14) or above versions.

Mainly I belive this [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764506/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-on-activity-showdialog-int-bundle) explians about the **java.lang.NoSuchMethodError**.

**Question**

**1).**  The problem is how can I identify if the bluetooth socket is Connected or Not with the devices that runs Android OS version below than 4.0 (API level 14).

If someone has a solution to achive this in a devices that runs a lower version than Android version 4.0 would like to hear. Thanks inadvance...!!!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(receiver,
                new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED));

getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(receiver,
                new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED));

private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action))
        {
            // LOG - Connected
        }
        else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equals(action))
        {
            // LOG - Disconnected
        }
    }
}
```

This will start a BroadcastReceiver when you are connected to another device.
I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: will you please explain what is action